# element of array as function to see other elements?

Tags: php, arrays

I don't speak very good English, not sure about title so will try to explain what i need to do:

I am making log parser.
I have 3 dynamic arrays (read from .log file) containing corresponding elements:

```
$personName //array of strings, can contain same name
$itemName   //array of strings, can contain same name
$itemAmount //array of numbers
```

Sample arrays:

```
$personName = array("Adam", "Maria", "Adam", "Adam");
$itemName = array("paper", "paper", "pen", "paper");
$itemAmount = array(11, 25, 2, 64);
```

I would like to sort (by person and item) and count (by amount) those arrays, eg. to print:

```
Total there are '100' 'paper' and '2' 'pen'.
'Adam' have '75' 'paper' and '2 'pen'.
'Maria' have '25' 'paper'.
```

This would allow me to get % of each item each person have, eg.:

```
'Adam' have '75'% of all 'paper' and '100'% of all 'pen'.
'Maria' have '25'% of all 'paper'.
```

I have arrays with unique names:

```
$persons = array_keys (array_flip ($personName));
$items = array_keys (array_flip ($itemName));
```

I did tried different combinations of for loops with foreach, but I struggle to find any solution.
Can somebody help me to get right approach?
(sorry if this is too basic, i really tried to look for solution and I'am very new to programming, started learning 3 days ago with this project)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
<?php
    $personName = array("Adam", "Maria", "Adam", "Adam", "Mihai");
    $itemName = array("paper", "paper", "pen", "paper", 'pencil');
    $itemAmount = array(11, 25, 2, 64, '18');


    $items = array();
    $persons = array();
    foreach($itemName as $id => $name){
        $items[$name] += $itemAmount[$id]; // we are adding amount for each item to $items array
        $persons[$personName[$id]][$name] += $itemAmount[$id]; // we are adding every item with amount to each persons
    }

    echo "Total there are "; // we are looping in each $items to display totals
    $i = 0;
    foreach($items as $nr => $item){

        echo "'".$item."' '".$nr."'";

        if($i < count($items)-2){ // this is for 'and' or ',' in case of multiple items
            echo ", ";
        } elseif($i < count($items)-1){
            echo " and ";
        }
        $i++;
    }

    echo '<br />';

    foreach($persons as $one => $value ){ // we are looping in each persons to display what they have
        echo "'".$one."' have ";
        $i = 0;
        foreach($value as $val => $number){

            echo "'".$number."' '".$val."'";

            if($i < count($value)-2){ // this is for 'and' or ',' in case of multiple items
                echo ", ";
            } elseif($i < count($value)-1){
                echo " and ";
            }

            $i++;
        }
        echo '.<br />';

    }

    // print_r($items); // will result in all items
    // print_r($persons); // will result in every person with every item

?>
```

Now you can manage `%`.

Comment: Thank you very very much! now i have something to play with fro next few days ;) Love StockOverflow!